# Rails Server crashing upon running getting "no such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently cloned a github repo and i'm trying to get it to work on my mac. I cloned it, did bundle install and got all the gems installed. When I try to do "rails server" I get an error:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:86:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/Teamly/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:86:in `database_configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:57
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/Teamly/config/environment.rb:5
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `polyglot_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/Teamly/config.ru:3
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails301/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/Teamly/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/Teamly/config.ru:1
```

What can I do to fix this problem? I don't have a database.yml, which is the issue. However, neither did the repo when I cloned it. Why is it looking for a file that wasn't suppose to be there to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When people push their repo on github, they exclude configuration files from that repo. You'll need to create a database.yml file in order to make your application work.

Here's an example of it.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: bibapp_development
  username: root
  password: 

test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: bibapp_test
  username: root
  password:

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: bibapp_production
  username: root
  password:
```

Comment: Is there any way to make mysql create this file automatically? I'm just not sure what info I should put in here. Like if i just want to create a blank DB so I can test the running app?

Comment: You'll have to create it manually. I guess you've just started learning rails, so chances are that you are using it in development mode. So enter your mysql servers details in it. by default, your username will be `root` there will be no password. You just have to enter the database's name and you are good to go

Comment: Yes, I am still somewhat new to rails. I can't do rake db:create without having database.yml created, but it asks for the database name without have the database created...kind of confusing. When I try to do rake db:create after making the yml file, I get this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: The field `database` in given example is used to specify your databases name. Create a database and then specify its name in the `database` field for development environment.